# Props onClose doesn't work on my Modal (Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, components, jsx

I am currently trying to close my modal by setting the state variable `openModal` to `false` with the function `handleClose` by clicking on the background. I thought that using the `onClose` props would do it but when I am clicking on the background, nothing happens. It was working fine before I put my `Modal` in a component. Any Idea how can I solve this ?

Thank you:)

```
const ModalReservation = ({openModal, setOpenModal}) => {

     ...
      const handleClose = () => setOpenModal(false);

      return (
      {openModal ?
      <Modal
        open={openModal}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
     ...
```

Comment: I believe it's an issue with the clickaway listener, because your modal is in a component. Maybe this will be of help to you. :) https://mui.com/components/click-away-listener/

Comment: It also looks like there is an onBackdropClick event as well. https://mui.com/api/modal/

Comment: Thank you ! But I just saw that in the console I have this message 'Uncaught TypeError: setOpenModal is not a function' everytime I click on the background.

Comment: I tried to use props instead to see if there is any difference but still nothing.

Comment: You need to show all of your code. From this it looks like you don't even have a state value to set to openModal

Answer (score 0):

I've made a dumb mistake in my other page instead of giving the props setOpenModal I gave setOpen.